# MySQL Connector won't open

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio, database-connection

I have what should be a trivial test here that is stubbornly refusing to work. On "Open" an exception "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" is thrown.

MySQL.Data is Version 6.4.4.0 and is referenced in my visual studio project, which builds without errors. MySQL is V 5.5.16. The test is built using Visual Studio 2008 with Windows Forms and and is launched via a Button,

I have tried this both under Windows XP and Windows 7, on different boxes. I gather from 
 [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)  that it is permissible to use PASSWORD, PWD, UID, User Name, UserName, SERVER, HOST, and numerous variations on the keywords in the connection string, and I have tried them all with equal lack of success.

I am confident that my username, password, and host name are correct. I am able to connect to my local MySQL DB via the command line using the same username and password.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
// and the ususal MS stuff...
     private void ToMySQL()
            {                
                MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection("DataSource=Localhost;Username=root;Password=xxxx;database=data_xxx");        
                try
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("OK");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

These things usually turn out to be something totally trivial, but if so it's so trivial that it's invisible to me.

What have I missed?

Edit-Addendum: Answers so far have with one exception (npi) duplicated what fails. If the problem is environmental, where might I look?

Comment: Have you tried Server= instead of DataSource=? I usually get good results looking [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for connection strings.

Comment: @ssamuel I looked at that site and 30 others. If you read my question carefully you will see that I did try SERVER, as well as other alternatives. I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string -

```
User Id=<user_name>;Host=<host_name>;Port=<3306>;Database=<db_name>;Password=<your_password>
```

Change all <...> values.

Comment: No joy. Exception: "Input string was not in a correct format." Why did you think it might work?

Comment: We use this string in our code (for the similar components - dotConnect for MySQL). Have a look at this link (it may be helpful) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectionstring

Comment: It is also may be a connection error. Try to connect with mysql command line tool - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html; or with dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Comment: As I stated in the original question, I can connect reliably via the command line.

Comment: Can you cannect to another MySQL server (with lower version)?

Comment: Aha! Yes, I was able to connect to a Server version 5.1.30 running on another machine - but whether this is a version problem or some other permissions issue I have no idea.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there can be something like 'bad handshake' error - when provider or driver does not support new server version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4803/discussion-between-mickeyf-and-devart)